# Arrive versus get

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Suppose I want to tell to other people I just arrived to some place.
Which is the most common way to say it ?

> I have just got here;
>   I just got here;
>   I just arrived now.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction was that "I just got here" is probably the most common.  NGram supports that [assumption](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20have%20just%20got%20here,I%20just%20got%20here,I%20just%20arrived%20now&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Also, "I just arrived" would be much more common than any of the other options, but still not as common as "I just got here."